# How to get the host protocol in import JSP

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, jsp

I am having two JSP files in my main application whereas one is MAIN.jsp and another one is CSS & JS import.jsp file.

MAIN.jsp is the main page of main application.The import.jsp file will import the CSS and JS of partner application in MAIN.jsp file which is used for support the few functionality with main application as partner.

But all the application (Main and Partner) are deployed in same server. So basically the host name of both the application will not change but context root alone will get change.

i have used jsp import tag to import the import.jsp in MAIN.jsp like mentioned below code.

## **MAIN.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
   <c:import url="resourceImport/import.jsp">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

## **import.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
   <link url="http://hostName/DifferentContext/example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="test/css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hostName/DifferentContext/sample.js" > </script> 
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently i have hard coded the partner HTTP URL in import.jsp for load all the resource in MAIN.jsp file. **But moving forward we are planing to run the application in HTTP and HTTPS environment.**

So how can i make it dynamic way of getting protocol in import.jsp file. I have tried following methods to get the protocol dynamically but its not working.

## **Method 1:**

*Removing Protocol and make it relative URL*

```
<head>
   <link url="//hostName/DifferentContext/example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="test/css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//hostName/DifferentContext/sample.js" > </script> 
</head>
```

## **Method 2**

*Removing Protocol and Host name and make it relative URL*

```
<head>
   <link url="//DifferentContext/example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="test/css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//DifferentContext/sample.js" > </script> 
</head>
```

So could you please anyone help me to get resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If there is *anything* that makes it worth to use https (and these days there *is*), I'd opt for less hassle and just go https *everywhere*.

No more worries, no accidental information leak and protocol change. Easier maintenance and no later update will inadvertently bring back a wrong protocol link.

Check [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) as an option to force compliant browsers to not bother with any http connection attempt in the future.

That being said, relative links are another way to stay in the same protocol and probably beneficial: You rarely want to hard code domain names into your applications - Depending on the programming style that you're using in your app, you might want to use page-relative links (`../DifferentContext/example.css`) or server-relative (`/DifferentContext/example.css`). Protocol relative is fine as well, but hardcodes the domain name.

Yet another option is to make that location completely configurable. This way you can decide later (provided that you've changed *all* occurrences to the configured value): `${config.theOtherAppBaseUrl}/example.css`. With this, you can try out all the different options yourself and within 10 minutes. And change your mind later, when you come to the conclusion that it's worth to go https everywhere.

(Note: You have an issue in your question's code: The last link refers to `//DifferentContext....`, which would assume that DifferentContext is a hostname - this is a protocol relative URL)